# Weaviate img2vec-neural Google Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-run, weaviate

I'm currently playing around with weaviate.
The goal is to make an image search engine for similar product images. I am now running it locally on docker desktop and everything works great.
Weaviate offers cloud services, but no container with my preferred engine **img2vec-neural**.

> Not applicable to WCS.
> This module is not available on Weaviate Cloud Services.

as seen in the documentation:
https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/modules/retriever-vectorizer-modules/img2vec-neural

My question is, if it would be possible to host this approx. 7.2 GB img2vec-pytorch:resnet50 file on Google Cloud Run and make requests to that cloud server from my application.
It seems to be a huge file and there must be drawbacks I'm sure.

Things that come to my mind:

- Pricing for keeping a server running this big
- Cold starts

I tried to find solutions with Googles own vertex AI, but i think this product doesn't fit my use case.

Maybe you have a good idea on how I could tackle the problem.
Maybe use another vectorizer that runs on weaviate cloud services?

Answer (score 1):

Running img2vec-neural on WCS is possible through a custom deployment.

You can contact hello@weaviate.io for help setting up a custom deployment.